# Xcode commitEditingStyle UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a project I have been working on. The code giving me problems worked yesterday and I haven't made any changes to that part of the code since, when I tried to run it today it wasn't working.

The problem is that when I swipe across the cell to delete it it's not detected and commitEditingStyle method is never run.

I also made another project just to test out the commitEditingStyle method and it was working fine. I also cleaned the project(Product -> Clean) and reset the iOS simulator.

What else can I try?

Here's my code, don't worry about NSUserDefaults, that's for saving the changes after you delete the cell.

```
   -(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES; }
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.taskObjects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSMutableArray *newTaskObjectsData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(Model *task in self.taskObjects)
        {
            [newTaskObjectsData addObject:[self taskObjectAsPropertyList:task]];
        }

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newTaskObjectsData forKey:USER_KEY];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong!  I had another method in the viewController that I was not aware was there.

```
    -(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Fixed it by setting the return value to UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete.

Answer (score 0):

> I Hope it's help you

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
{
            [self.taskObjects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSMutableArray *newTaskObjectsData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(Model *task in self.taskObjects)
        {
            [newTaskObjectsData addObject:[self taskObjectAsPropertyList:task]];
        }

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newTaskObjectsData forKey:USER_KEY];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; // please set automatic animation 

    }
 // here you can reload your tableview
[self.tasksTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: It still does't work, the problem is that the method commitEditingStyle never gets called when the user swipes right on the cell.